# Model data not binding to html template in Backbone,Marionette

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, marionette

I am new to backbone and Marionette.
My requirement is, 
I have a main grid having few rows. If i select a row from grid i need to fetch the details and display on the same page.
Binding the grid is working fine. But when i click on the row data is not binding to html template. I am unable to find out the issue.

Below is my html template for row details

```
<script id="selected-broker-details-tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <div id="pnl-broker-details" class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">

            Broker Details

        </div>

        <div id="broker-details-container" class="panel-body">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="inputbrokerName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">BrokerName</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputbrokerName" placeholder="Broker Name" value="{{BrokerName}}">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="inputMnemonic" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Mnemonic</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMnemonic" placeholder="Mnemonic" value="{{Mnemonic}}">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Backbone view declaration

```
App.Views.BrokerDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
            },
            el: '#details',
            template: brokerTemplates.BrokerDetailsTempalte,
            render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template({}));
            }
        });
```

Model and collection declaration

```
var BrokderDetails = Backbone.Model.extend({
            BrokerId: null,
            BrokerName: null,
            Mnemonic: null,
            OASYSMnemonic: null
        });
var BrokerDetailsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            initialize: function (options) {
                this.model = BrokderDetails;
                this.url = '/api/BrokerSelections/SelectedBroker/';
            }
            ,
            setParam: function (str) {
                this.url = '/api/BrokerSelections/SelectedBroker/' + str;
                this.fetch();
            },
            parse: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        });
```

click event in main grid

```
events: {
                "click .selection": "selectedBroker",
            },
selectedBroker: function (e) {
                var details = new BrokerDetailsCollection();
                var brokerdetails = new App.Views.BrokerDetails({ model: null, collection: details });
                details.setParam($(e.currentTarget).data("id"));
                details.fetch();
                brokerdetails.render();
            },
```

Now there are 2 issues,
1. Click event is firing 2 times, if i select a row i main grid
2. Model data is not binding to html template. I mean html template is displayed, but with empty values in textboxes

Comment: If you post a jsfiddle, it will be much easier to know where it goes wrong.

Comment: Which template engine do you use? If you are using `underscore` then your template is wrong. You should use `<%=BrokerName %>` instead of `{{BrokerName}}`. Secondly to add defaults to your model, you need to define them in `defaults` parameter, not as individual properties as you have in `BrokderDetails`. And you have strange `render` method in your `BrokerDetails view` which does not get any model to render from, it must be something like `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));`